# What can one learn on Tisha B'Av?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav

What are you allowed to learn on Tisha B'Av in general particularity which Gemaras?

Comment: If you cant learn Here is another option:
http://www.kiruv.com/toolsForSharing/ProjectInspire/Wiping_A_Tear.asp

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/is-there-a-document-available-online-with-all-the-sections-permitted-to-learn-on

Comment: Anything that won't make you happy.

Comment: @DoubleAA So what about someone who derives pleasure from learning ANY part of Torah even the "sad" stuff?

Comment: @Yehoshua Find something sad.

Comment: @DoubleAA At the end of the day though it's still Torah. I'm happy to have gained the knowledge whether it be in Nach, Gemara, Medresh, Halacha, etc.

Comment: @Yehoshua http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75220/may-one-learn-torah-on-tisha-bav-if-he-enjoys-learning-anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [ואלו מגלחין במועד](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2a03.htm)
- Gittin 55b אמר רבי יוחנן through ... I think almost the bottom of 58a.  (Note that the chapter is called "those who are damaged.")
- The minor tractate of Semachot
- Rambam's [Laws of the Mourner and his Mourning](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e4.htm) and corresponding portions of Shulchan Aruch.
- Book of Job
- Other calamitous parts of the prophets

Comment: I believe there are also opinions that say you're allowed to learn your regular daily Torah portions (Chumash/Tehillim/Tanya, Rambam, Daf Yomi, etc.). Although others say you should postpone them till after the fast is over.

Comment: YS, the guideline on editing other users' answers is to respect them.  Stuff like fixing typos or linking terms to wikipedia is okay.  Your point here was different and significant enough that it belongs as a comment, or you can write your own answer (including whatever pieces of mine you like).

Comment: I am sorry I thought it was a signifigant point you failed to mention.

Comment: I learn that portion of Gittin every year, usually Erev Tisha B'Av but sometimes Tisha B'Av itself. From the section "Because of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza" up to the story of the apprentice who tricked his master and married his wife.