# Is the material permitted to learn on Tisha B'av available online?

Tags: halacha, internet, torah-study, tisha-bav

[From Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/h/9av/oal/48944076.html):

> Other prohibitions include...Learning Torah, since this is a joyful activity. It is permitted to learn texts relevant to Tisha B'Av and mourning -- e.g. the Book of Lamentations, Book of Job, parts of Tractate Moed Katan, Gittin 56-58, Sanhedrin 104, Yerushalmi end of Ta'anis, and the Laws of Mourning. In-depth study should be avoided. (MB 554:4)

Is the material that we are permitted to learn on Tisha B'av available online?

Ideally, I'd like to have some sort of document that includes the different sources that I can save to my computer, for offline reference. I understand it's not realistic to expect a pdf of the complete books of Iyov and Eicha, but all the different Talmudic sources in one pdf would be useful.

If that's not available, it would be nice to know where the material is availabe online.

Also, which parts of Moed Katan specifically?

Comment: A single document would be impossible.  Just eicha and Iyov is more than a single document.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Not a traditional answer, but from personal experience I guarantee you won't feel happy after reading these http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18383/is-chayecha-kodmin-a-chiyuv-or-a-right#comment44330_18391

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Let's put together a list here.

- The books of Lamentations ([original Hebrew](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t32.htm) / [JPS English translation](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3201.htm)) and Job ([original Hebrew](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t27.htm) / [JPS English translation](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2701.htm)):
- Jeremiah: all sections critical of the Jews' behavior or about the destruction.  This is most of the book.  Starting from chapter 1, one can continue until chapter 29, skipping the few verses of consolation that appear. Chapters 30-33 are largely prophecies of consolation, and should be skipped.  Chapters 34-36 are again negative prophecies.
  Chapters 37-38 are preliminary to the siege of Jerusalem;
  [Chapter 39](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1139.htm) ([JPS English Translation](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1139.htm)) begins the account of the fall of Jerusalem, and the account of the destruction continues until chapter 45, inclusive. Chapter 46 begins a section about the other nations, which should be skipped; chapter 52 (the last chapter) is again about the fall of Jerusalem.
- Talmud Moed Katan, most of the [third chapter](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/l/l2a03.htm) (13b--18a and 19b to the end) which deals with mourning and excommunication.
- Talmud Gittin ([55B](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2559&size=2)-[58A](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2564&size=2)) regarding the destruction  (some of it available in Artscroll [Hebrew](http://savvima.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Tisha-BAv-Gemara-Hebrew.pdf) and [English](http://savvima.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/Tisha-BAv-Gemara.pdf)).
- Talmud Sanhedrin [96A](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3801&size=1)-97 (English [here](http://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_96.html)). ([Nitei Gavriel says pages 96 and 97](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46440&pgnum=85), but it appears that the story of the destruction of the first Beit Hamikdash ends at the end of 96B)
- Yerushalmi about the destruction and about the laws of Tisha B'Av ([Taanis chapter 4, halachot 5-6](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2904.htm)).
- Rambam's [Laws of the Mourner and his Mourning](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e4.htm).
- Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim, laws of Tisha B'Av and mourning for Jerusalem (secs. [552](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2912)-[561](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2923)); Yoreh De'ah, laws of burial and mourning (pretty much everything from [sec. 339](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6916) to the end).
- [Midrash on Megilat Eicha](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/33182) (or [starting page 348 in Midrash Rabbah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&pgnum=348)).
- This [Sefer Kinot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/51217), published by "Ohr HaBahir" in 1965, includes the [Midrash Lekach Tov on Eicha](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51217&pgnum=275), as well as the [Midrash Eileh Ezkerah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51217&pgnum=309), which discusses how the Ten Martyrs were killed.

Sections dealing with consolation, or punishment of the other nations, should be skipped.

Comment: Only starting with ch. 39 of Jeremiah? I was under the impression that all of it is fine, except for the parts (like chs. 30-31) that have prophecies of comfort and restoration.

Comment: @Alex you could be right; I just recall hearing about the debate whether you can read straight through starting at 39.

Comment: What about that which is not strictly Halachic, namely Chasidus and Musar?

Comment: @yoel: Nitei Gavriel [says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46440&pgnum=87) that Chasidus (on the topics listed here) is fine; as an example, he cites a [directive](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14932&pgnum=277) from the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l to study the Tzemach Tzedek's Reshimos on Eicha. On the next page Nitei Gavriel also says that Musar (apparently of any kind) is also okay, "because it breaks a person's heart."

Comment: @Shalom: The Mishna Berurah 544:2 S"K 2 says that we are not allowed to bad parts that will happen to the other nations. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=61 . Do you know who says we are allowed to?

Comment: FYI: [Hebrew Wikisource](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/) includes a "יצירת ספר" link which allows a user to collate texts into one page (I think) and print them together. (English Wikisource has the same, but I don't think one can combine pages from the Hebrew Wikisource and [the English](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/) into one 'book'.)

Comment: What about other commentaries on *Eichah* in addition to the Midrash Rabbah?

Comment: HaRav Yishak Shelit"a writes (Yalkut Yosef) that it is permissible to learn Musar that is Mekarev someone to do Teshuva.

Answer (score 4):

In previous years I received and email from artscroll, a pdf with the pages mentioned of gitin.

It can be found [here](https://artscroll.files.wordpress.com/2008/07/gittin-volume-02-55b-56a.pdf).

Comment: @avi: For some reason, those pdfs do not continue all the way through the relevant Gemara. It is just 55B and 56A. Still useful, though.