# using this website on tisha b'av?

Tags: torah-study, tisha-bav, stackexchange

It is known that one's not allowed to learn on tisha b'av; what is the halachic status of using this site on tisha b'av?

Comment: This site has some questions that are not torah-learning, like the one about how paying a mohel works or the one about tools for minyan management (to pick two on the main page now).  So, no source, but it seems like it would depend on what you're doing here.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get your answer tomorrow night :) . There are Tisha-Bav specific questions, such as this one: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/is-the-material-permitted-to-learn-on-tisha-bav-available-online?rq=1

Comment: I don't understand the question. This site is just like anything else. You can use it to learn about things which are permitted on Tisha b'Av and you can't use it to learn those things which are not permitted.

Comment: @DoubleAA, perhaps he's concerned about stumbling across material he's not allowed to learn while reading other stuff?  user1445, could you clarify your question?