# Permitted to learn Perush Hamilos on Davening on Tisha Bi'Av

Tags: halacha, tefilla, torah-study, tisha-bav

If someone learns the simple translation of each word in davening each day. Can he still do it on Tisha Bi'Av?

It is either considered learning or not.

If it is considered learning then you can't do it.

If it is not considered learning that you can do it.

(From Aish.com http://www.aish.com/h/9av/oal/48944076.html [Is the material permitted to learn on Tisha B'av available online?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/is-the-material-permitted-to-learn-on-tisha-bav-available-online):

Other prohibitions include...Learning Torah, since this is a joyful activity. It is permitted to learn texts relevant to Tisha B'Av and mourning -- e.g. the Book of Lamentations, Book of Job, parts of Tractate Moed Katan, Gittin 56-58, Sanhedrin 104, Yerushalmi end of Ta'anis, and the Laws of Mourning. In-depth study should be avoided. (MB 554:4)

So is it considered learning Torah?

Comment: As a reminder, consult your rabbi regarding any practical questions, perhaps using what you read here as helpful pointers to frame your question (to your rabbi) more intelligently.

Comment: This is not really for me, I just wanted to know the parameters of learning on Tisha Bi'Av

Comment: Why is there a -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to understand the words you use in prayer. In fact, if you don't understand the hebrew words, you really should be praying in the language that you do understand. So if it is the translation of parts of the Tisha Be'av prayers, which also of course include regular daily prayers, it should be permitted.

The source for this that if you don't understand Hebrew, you should really pray in the language you understand, can be found in Shulchan Aruch, Orech Chaim 101 Magen avrahan s"k 5 and Shulachan Aruch Harav ibid 101:5 (quoting from Sefer Chassidim and Asara Mamaros)

Comment: Do you have a source for the first part of your answer?