# Reviewing Torah on Tisha Bi'Av

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav

Are you allowed to review Torah that you already learnt before Tisha Bi'Av on Tisha Bi'Av?

From Aish.com http://www.aish.com/h/9av/oal/48944076.html: ([Is the material permitted to learn on Tisha B'av available online?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/is-the-material-permitted-to-learn-on-tisha-bav-available-online))

Other prohibitions include...Learning Torah, since this is a joyful activity. It is permitted to learn texts relevant to Tisha B'Av and mourning -- e.g. the Book of Lamentations, Book of Job, parts of Tractate Moed Katan, Gittin 56-58, Sanhedrin 104, Yerushalmi end of Ta'anis, and the Laws of Mourning. In-depth study should be avoided. (MB 554:4)

So does this rule of not learning Torah on Tisha Bi'Av only apply to **NEW** Torah you learn on Tisha Bi'Av, and does not apply to just reviewing Torah.

So my question is: does this rule (of not learning Torah on Tisha Bi'Av) apply to both learning new Torah and reviewing Torah or just learning new Torah?

(I was thinking that maybe it does not apply to reviewing because you do not get as happy for just reviewing Torah)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, even reviewing is not allowed. Words of Torah are intrinsically "mesamchei lev", make the heart happy and are therefore not permited to be studied on Tisha B'Av. Besides, review can almost inevitably bring to new insights not though of before (ain bais hamedrash b'lo chidush).  An easy and meaningful fast to all.

Comment: Do you have any sources for these assertions? After all, we don't know you that we should trust you.