# Can you learn portions of Avot D'Rav Nattan on Tish'a B'Av?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, tisha-bav, avot-derabbi-natan

[This M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9368/5275) provides a list of permissible learning items on Tish'a B'Av. All these items are somehow related to the themes of mourning, the Temple destruction, etc.

*Avot D'Rav Natan* has several *Mishnayot* that seem to relate to the theme of Tish'a B'Av related to the setruction of Jerusalem. Examples:

[Avot D'Rav Natan 4:4 and 4:5](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/4-2.htm) 
Rav Yohanan ben Zakkai's request from Vespasian for Yavneh

[Avot D'Rav Natan 6:3](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/6-2.htm)
Near the end of Mishnah; story of Kalba Savu'a who had enough  food to feed everyone in Jerusalem for 22 years. Yet, the Zealots destroyed his storehouses

Would it be appropriate to learn these? Why weren't these included in the list?

Comment: It's possible that since these are already recounted in other locations in the Talmud, they just suggest you learn the relevant Talmud rather than skipping around in the more obscure AdR"N

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I had thought of that angle, but I'm uncertain if everything mentioned in AD"N is also mentioned elsewhere. Personally, if I have everything in one *sefer*, it's easier to learn that way than procuring multiple *sefarim* to locate each of these stories, individually, no?

Comment: On the contrary, the ones you mentioned are cherrypicked from across several places. In the Gemaras we learn on Tb"A they are enclosed within larger relevant sugyos that are ALSO learned/learnable on Tb"A.

Comment: If the content is appropriate you can learn it it. It doesn't matter what the name of the book is or what else is near it. All the lists you've ever seen are approximations.

Comment: (I think you mean the end of Avot D'Rabbi Natan 6:3. Also, technically they are *braitot* not *mishnayot*.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Tanna v'sheeyer](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A8)* - Anything fitting the mood of the day is acceptable (at least without *iyun* [in-depth analysis]; see also sources cited by @WFB in comments below which are lenient even with regard to *iyun*). It would be impossible to have a comprehensive list since *Torah SheBaal Peh* (the oral Torah) is constantly expanding. (My assumption is that these specific passages were also not included in the list because they are relatively short.) See also, e.g., the [Aruch HaShulchan (554:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.554.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) who permits reading the sad passages in *Neviim* left unmentioned by the [*Brayta*](http://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.30a.49?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all):

> ויראה לי דכן דברים הרעים שבשארי נביאים – מותר לקרות. ומה שהש"ס חשיב רק ירמיה – משום דבירמיה יש הרבה דברים רעים.
>
> It seems to me that, so too, one is allowed to read the sad passages [lit: bad things] in the other Prophets and the reason the Talmud only mentioned Jeremiah is because there are many sad passages in Jeremiah.

(This inclusive understanding, by the way, is the basis why later codes and commentaries [e.g. *Levush* cited by *[Mishna Berura](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.554.3?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)*] added to the original Talmudic list.)

Comment: The Aruch HaShulchan permits *iyun* as well https://www.sefaria.org/Aruch_HaShulchan.1.554.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=en This is also the view of R. Chaim Soloveitchik and the Chazon Ish

Comment: See also here (4-5): https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%93#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A9.D7.A4.D7.93_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93

Comment: This is a good answer and I agree with the principle, but do you have a source that specifically says we can expand the list based on svara (i..e., for your last sentence)? Relatedly, I have heard from a few rebbeim that one can learn Shut MiMaamakim on Tisha b'Av, which fits with this idea.

Comment: @Avraham not offhand