# Do the laws of not learning on tisha b'av also apply to Ches Av?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, fast-days, tisha-bav

I heard  that on Tisha bi'Av the rules of not learning Torah also apply on Ches Av (the eighth of Av).

So I have a few questions on Chess Bi'Av.

1. Is there a source for this
2. This question [What can one learn on Tisha B'Av?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-can-one-learn-on-tisha-bav) says some things you can learn on Tisha B'av, so my question is: Does all of these things apply to Ches B'av or some things are more lenient and you can learn different/more things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[O Ch 553 (2) Rema near the end](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=62) says

> After Chatzos on Erev Tisha B'Av, the Minhag is to learn only things
>   that may be learned on Tisha B'Av.

The source for what can be learnt on 9th Av is mentioned in [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9364/is-the-material-permitted-to-learn-on-tisha-bav-available-online). It is [O Ch 554 (1-4)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=63). There seems to be no special leniences for 8th Av afternoon.

My Rav said (and I saw it [here](http://www.chaiodom.com/halacha.html)) that

> Certainly one may learn sifre mussar for the purpose of t’shuva.

(Not quite relevant to the question but of general interest - the [The Chofetz Chaim Heritage Foundation](http://www.cchfusa.org/TishaBav_14/)  arranges programmes worldwide on tisha b'av to encourage teshuvah.

Many shuls have special tisha b'av programmes to encourage understanding the day and to learn its lessons.)