# What happens when Tisha B'Av falls out on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, tisha-bav

When Tisha B'Av falls on Shabbos, it is pushed off until Sunday, as it is this year. On Tisha B'Av, we practice several acts of mourning, such as not learning, sitting on low chairs, and fasting. Which of these, if any, apply on Shabbos, which is the actual anniversary of the Churban?

Related is [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17883/do-the-customs-in-regards-to-yud-av-apply-to-yud-aleph-av-on-a-year-when-the) regarding the Nine Days' restrictions.

Comment: That's specifically discussing tashmish. My question is broader and refers to *anything* prohibited on Shabbos.

Comment: @DonielF That question is about anything. Tashmish is just an example

Answer (score 1):

As per [this article](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/946845/jewish/Tisha-BAv-on-Shabbat-or-Sunday.htm) (note that this is a Chabad article):

1. Public displays of mourning are prohibited.
2. Marital relations are prohibited.
3. With the exceptions of the [texts permitted to be learned on Tisha B'Av](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-can-one-learn-on-tisha-bav) and those that are a part of davening, one is not allowed to learn Torah after Chatzos. Thus, those kehillos that normally say Pirkei Avos during the summer skip it this week. (Note: many kehillos do not hold of this, and Torah is learned all afternoon.)
4. Shalosh Se'udos is conducted normally, and one may even eat meat if one wishes. It is not done mournfully, as a Seudah HaMafsekes usually is. However, it must be completed before Shekiah.
5. Normal chairs and shoes may be worn all throughout Shabbos and even Bein HaShemashos. They are removed after Barchu.
6. Havdalah is pushed off to Sunday, though Atah Chonantanu/Baruch Hamavdil and the brachah of Borei Meorei HaEish are said Motzaei Shabbos. We do not say Vihi Noam. On Sundah night, when Havdalah is finally made, we don't say the Brachos on the spices or candle.

Comment: This list is not according to everyone.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I had assumed that the fact it was a Chabad article made that clear, but I'll edit that in. I made the answer a community wiki for the community to edit in where their minhagim differ.