# Studying the Tochacha in Tish'a B'Av

Tags: tisha-bav, rebuke-tochacha

Would one be permitted to study the Tochacha on Tish'a B'Av?

It's not about the fast **and is not mentioned in the [list of things one may learn on Tish'a B'Av](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2213/501)** as it doesn't pertain to the destruction per se, but it is not a happy subject matter and ultimately does **predict the destruction and exile**.

And, if permitted, would there be a difference between learning the Tochacha in בְּחֻקֹּתַי and כִּי-תָבוֹא?

Any sources or conjectures appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can one learn on Tisha B'Av?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/what-can-one-learn-on-tisha-bav)

Comment: @DonielF - I clarified - in bold - why I think it's not a dup.

Comment: @danny maybe there are other lists where it is mentioned? Why does it not being in the list in that answer make it not a duplicate?

Comment: I'll comment before this gets closed; I didn't VTC ... yet.. The Tochacha definitely mentions directly some of the tragedies that actually occurred. Most notably, for me, was the mentioning of women eating their children. I think at the least, one should be able to read at least those verses with explanations as these seem to relate directly to TB.

Comment: @DanF, IIRC the Tochacha is a build up of tragedies that culminate in the Churban.

Comment: @DannySchoemann If you're talking about the one in *Ki Tavo*, not exactly. It culminates with the warning of exile to Egypt where no one would be interested in buying us even as a slave.

Comment: @DanF - true, it doesn't explicitly mention the destruction, but it clearly mentions the exile... and being sold as slaves.